# How to customise telegram bot buttons?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I have  some names in a list with unknown list length.For each name in the list should need a button customised based on the total number of buttons

```
name = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,....]

main_keyboard = [[Button.inline(name[0]), Button.inline(name[1])]]
```

This will create buttons side side like

```
button1 button2
```

What I want output is
if the length of list is 3

```
button1 button2
button3
```

if the length of list is 4

```
button1 button2
button3 button4
```

If the length of the list is 6

```
button1 button2 button3
button4 button5 button6
```

if length of the list is 8

```
button1 button2 button3
button4 button5 button6
button7 button8
```

If the length of list is greater than 12 , then the button should be in next page

Comment: Note that pagination is an entirely different topic to the shape of the buttons matrix, Telethon will let you arrange your buttons in different rows and columns, but pagination will need to be implemented to suit your usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Array in the main keyboard array is a separate row.

To get the desired output, you'll need to slit your array of buttons in to chunks of your desired size:

- [How do I split a list into equally-sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks)

---

Set the chunk size based on the amount of buttons you wish on each line.